# WebVR show html content

Tags: web, three.js, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I'd like to create a virtual space where I want to mix 3D elements and html content. I have seem some demos with WebVR but didn't work for me. WebAR is also an interesting option.

Thanks

Comment: Please use the tag `augmented-reality` instead of `ar`. `ar` stands for _the Unix archiver utility, used primarily for maintaining static libraries._ on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible at the moment, because

- there is no proper way to get your hands on the rastered output of the HTML in order to use it as a texture in WebGL and
- there is no way to get any html-element shown in a WebVR-context

There is certainly work being done in both directions, but your best bets would probably be a-frame (https://aframe.io/) or reactVR (https://developer.oculus.com/blog/introducing-the-react-vr-pre-release/) which both at least have a bit of that html-feeling to it and can handle text pretty well (nothing compared to the power of html+css, but they will get there at some point).

Another option is to use a library like html2canvas (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to get some rendered output from a piece of html which you can then use as a texture. Also has it's limits but might be worth a try...

Have fun!